# How to use local as well as remote storage/database in same project?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am developing Online Examination system for LAN
This is going to be a client-server system which can be used by 60 users at a time.
I am planning to use MySql database running at LAN Server.

All Fine till here....

**The Case :**
(As per the organization for which a am developing a system)
**Some time the computers in the LAN loss the network/connectivity.**

Therefore I want to store All the answers given by the individual student to there computer (client) first and then want to transfer that data to the MySql running at server(error in the case of network failure : no issue) when student done with the exam.

**How can I achieve this ? Give me a suggestion or an idea ?**

P.s.- I do not want to use/install MySql on each n every client (MySql - Only on server).

Comment: Consider using Sqlite.

Comment: Check for internet connection availability, and download the data into an XML file. Next time there is no connection, use the XML data instead.

Comment: @SLaks - what about SQL Server CE

Comment: @HanletEscaño - Actually , instead of checking for the network connectivity , i want to store data at client first.

Comment: @Vikram: That will work equally well.

Comment: @SLaks - Ok. If I use SQL Server CE on client Then what should i do ? How to store data eventually to MySql form SQL CE.

Comment: DB Sync http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd918848.aspx